# Does Quelling Blade bonus apply to base damage or total damage?

Tags: dota-2

Is it based off the damage you get from scaling with your attribute, or is the extra damage from other items also included in the calculation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quelling Blade's bonus damage is calculated from your total damage, which is your base damage + stat based damage + any damage items. In DotA 1, Quelling Blade's bonus damage was a Unique Attack Modifier, so it had varying interactions with other UAM items such as Diffusal Blade/Desolator. In DotA2, this isn't the case.